# Change comment author after new comment posted

Tags: comments

I'm trying to update the user_id of a comment once it has been posted. It looks to see if the comment_author_email exists as a user in the users table, and if it does, attach that user to the comment.

```
function set_comment_author($comment_ID){
    global $wpdb;

    $comment = get_comment($comment_ID, ARRAY_A);
    if($comment["user_id"] == 0){
        $user = get_user_by('email', $comment["comment_author_email"]);
        if($user){
            $user_id = $user->ID;
            $comment["user_id"] = $user_id;
            wp_update_comment($comment); //This method doesn't work

            /*
             * This method doesn't work either
               $wpdb->update(   
                    $wpdb->prefix.'comments',
                    array(
                        'user_id' => $user_id
                    ),
                    array(
                        'comment_ID' => $comment_id
                    )
                );
            $wpdb->print_error();*/
        }
    }
}
add_action("comment_post", "set_comment_author", 10, 1);
```

I have done some debugging, and the action is being fired, the comment ID is coming through, and the user_id is being found. So the problem is updating the comment. Both wordpress function and database method don't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, being stupid, i was using `$comment_id`, I needed `$comment_ID`.

The `wp_update_comment()` function still didn't work though, if anyone can shed some light onto that.

Comment: Edit your question instead of posting this as an answer.

Comment: Any luck in solving this?